# Matplotlib: scrolling plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scroll

I'm new to Python and I want to implement a scrolling plot for a very long time series data. I've found an example from Matplotlib as follows.

http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_ScrollingPlot.html

When I run the example from the link, I found every time I scroll the plot and release the scrollbar, the scrollbar returns to the beginning. Want to scroll to the next position? I need to start to scroll from the beginning again.

I want to understand why it happens and how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an improved version of the example. (Disclaimer: I started digging into it half an hour ago, never before used wx/matplotlib scrollbars so there might be a much better solution.)

The path I took: first I checked the [wx scroll events](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_scroll_win_event.html), then found out that the canvas is [FigureCanvasWxAgg](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_wxagg_api.html) derived from wxPanel, inheriting [wxWindow](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html) methods. There you may find the scroll position handling methods `GetScrollPos` and `SetScrollPos`.

```
from numpy import arange, sin, pi, float, size

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent, id, 'scrollable plot',
                style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER,
                size=(800, 400))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.fig = Figure((5, 4), 75)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self.panel, -1, self.fig)
        self.scroll_range = 400
        self.canvas.SetScrollbar(wx.HORIZONTAL, 0, 5,
                                 self.scroll_range)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.canvas, -1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.panel.Fit()

        self.init_data()
        self.init_plot()

        self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.OnScrollEvt)

    def init_data(self):

        # Generate some data to plot:
        self.dt = 0.01
        self.t = arange(0,5,self.dt)
        self.x = sin(2*pi*self.t)

        # Extents of data sequence:
        self.i_min = 0
        self.i_max = len(self.t)

        # Size of plot window:
        self.i_window = 100

        # Indices of data interval to be plotted:
        self.i_start = 0
        self.i_end = self.i_start + self.i_window

    def init_plot(self):
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.plot_data = \
                  self.axes.plot(self.t[self.i_start:self.i_end],
                                 self.x[self.i_start:self.i_end])[0]

    def draw_plot(self):

        # Update data in plot:
        self.plot_data.set_xdata(self.t[self.i_start:self.i_end])
        self.plot_data.set_ydata(self.x[self.i_start:self.i_end])

        # Adjust plot limits:
        self.axes.set_xlim((min(self.t[self.i_start:self.i_end]),
                           max(self.t[self.i_start:self.i_end])))
        self.axes.set_ylim((min(self.x[self.i_start:self.i_end]),
                            max(self.x[self.i_start:self.i_end])))

        # Redraw:
        self.canvas.draw()

    def update_scrollpos(self, new_pos):
        self.i_start = self.i_min + new_pos
        self.i_end = self.i_min + self.i_window + new_pos
        self.canvas.SetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL, new_pos)
        self.draw_plot()

    def OnScrollEvt(self, event):
        evtype = event.GetEventType()

        if evtype == wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN_THUMBTRACK.typeId:
            pos = event.GetPosition()
            self.update_scrollpos(pos)
        elif evtype == wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN_LINEDOWN.typeId:
            pos = self.canvas.GetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            self.update_scrollpos(pos + 1)
        elif evtype == wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN_LINEUP.typeId:
            pos = self.canvas.GetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            self.update_scrollpos(pos - 1)
        elif evtype == wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN_PAGEUP.typeId:
            pos = self.canvas.GetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            self.update_scrollpos(pos - 10)
        elif evtype == wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN_PAGEDOWN.typeId:
            pos = self.canvas.GetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            self.update_scrollpos(pos + 10)
        else:
            print "unhandled scroll event, type id:", evtype

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(parent=None,id=-1)
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You may adjust e.g. the increments for PAGEUP/PAGEDOWN if you feel it too slow.

Also if you wish, the events can be handled separately setting up the specific event handlers instead of their collection `EVT_SCROLLWIN`, then instead of if/elifs there will be OnScrollPageUpEvt etc.